# WCF SVC file running under Which Identity?

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf

I have configured a Virtual Directory on IIS 6.0 running under UserA.
AppPool for the same is configured under Network Services.

I have one WCF svc file running under it, 
My question is:

Is it running on UserA Account Or Network Service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will use the identity setup on the AppPool

Comment: Means :Network Service
Could you please tell me how to change UserA

Comment: Change the app pool to use UserA.

Comment: I have tried, but it generates more issues. Whole application stops working.

"Service Unavailable"?

Comment: what do you see when you browse to the .svc page

Comment: "Service Unavailable" Message only.

Comment: How is UserA configured? Can you make UserA and admin on that box just to see if that's the reason?